# Is it possible to create new user using visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, controller

I did implement visualforce page Create new user.But issue can be occur (Error:Profile: Required fields are missing: [Profile]).Could you please say me How to solve this issue
Controller:

```
public class CreateNewUser{
 public User user;
public CreateNewUser(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{ 
  this.user= (User)controller.getrecord();
}
public List<selectOption> getLicense()
{
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    options.add(new selectOption('', '- None -')); 
     for (UserLicense users :[SELECT Id,Name FROM UserLicense])  
      {    
            options.add(new selectOption(users.Id, users.Name)); 
      }
    return options; 
}

public List<selectOption> getProfile() {
  List<selectOption> options1 = new List<selectOption>(); 
  options1.add(new selectOption('', '- None -'));
  for (Profile users1 :[SELECT Id,Name FROM Profile])  { 
          options1.add(new selectOption(users1.Id, users1.Name)); 
   } 
    return options1;
} 
}
```

Visualforce:

```
    <apex:page standardController="User" extensions="CreateNewUser" tabStyle="User">
   <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
        <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value=" Save "></apex:commandButton>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"></apex:commandButton>
                 </apex:pageBlockButtons>

              <apex:pageBlockSection title="User Information" columns="2" collapsible="false"> 

                  <apex:inputField value="{!User.IsActive}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!User.FirstName}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!User.Username}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!User.LastName}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!User.Email}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!User.alias}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!User.UserRoleId}"/>
                  </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.Phone}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.Extension}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.Fax}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.EmployeeNumber}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.Title}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.CompanyName}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.Division}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.Department}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.CommunityNickName}"/>

                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.ReceivesInfoEmails}" />
                   </apex:pageBlocksection>

                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="false" title="License">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="License" for="lic"></apex:outputLabel>
      <apex:selectList id="mgr" value="{!User.UserType}" size="1" title="Manager">
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!license}"></apex:selectOptions>
        <u> <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="selectedProfileId"/></u>
   </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Profile" for="pro"></apex:outputLabel>

                    <apex:selectList value="{!User.UserType}" multiselect="false" size="1" id="selectedProfileId">
                       <apex:selectOptions value="{!profile}" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 

               <apex:pageBlockSection title="Other Information" columns="1" collapsible="false">
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.EmailEncodingKey}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.TimeZoneSidKey}"/> 
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.LocaleSidKey}"/>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!User.LanguageLocaleKey}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockSection>

              </apex:pageBlock>
              </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem for now is right here:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!User.UserType}" multiselect="false" size="1" id="selectedProfileId">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!profile}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

The first line should be:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!User.ProfileId}" size="1" id="selectedProfileId">
```

You've inadvertently set the UserType field twice.